# Ābhassara Brahma World for anyone?

Tags: pali-canon, rebirth, sutras, suttas, brahma

According to Buddhism someone who reach a higher level of Meditation (Samadhi) would be born in the Brahma realm.

These beings are not sexually attracted to female gender (They don't have a female gender), They are with or without a Physical appearance.

But when Buddhism describe the destruction of a universe it says that beings from almost all the realms are born in this "[**Ābhassara World**](http://www.palikanon.com/english/pali_names/aa/aabhassara.htm)" which is a Brahma world.

---

But how does such a birth happen to any creature when they haven't reached a higher state of mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When other lower realms collapse the inhabitants are push to the existing realms of which Ābhassara World is one last standing, hence nearly every one in a collapsing universe ends up in this plane in the universe with an exception of a few who might be thrown into parallel universes 10,000 world system away.

But also if you cling on to false view then there is a high chance you might be born in another parallel universe, 10,000 world systems away (I would presume a cluster of world system collapse together), which is sustaining life other planes including (other planes exist only in 1 of the 4 phases in cycles of the universe.) but not conducive for a Buddha to appear. This might be either Abhi Dhamma or in later canonical works as I cannot find in any of the translations I have checked which are mostly suttas. [Apannaka Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/35.5-Apannaka-S-m60-piya.pdf) does mention wrong views lead to hell though.

[Aggañña Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/2.19-Agganna-S-d27-piya.pdf) and [Kosala Sutta 1](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/16.15-Kosala-S-1-a10.29-piya.pdf) deals with this subject matter. Also see: Gods and the [Universe in Buddhist Perspective: Essays on Buddhist Cosmology and related subjects](http://www.bps.lk/olib/wh/wh180.pdf) by Francis Story, [The Buddhist Concept of World](http://bhavanasociety.org/resource/the_buddhist_concept_of_world/) Bhikkhu T. Seelananda, [Parallel universes](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/R450-160524-Parallel-universes-RB150.pdf) by Piya Tan

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago I heard a dhamma talk about the contracting universe and recall the person saying that beings are either born in the formless worlds or born with consciousness bound to the heat element (an infinitesimal painful experience). Can't recall the source.